# 3" radon vent 4" roof jack

Tags: vent, radon

I have installed a 4" oatley vent flashing and drilled holes in roof and walls with a 4-1/8 bit.  Unfortunately the radon coupler out of the concrete is only 3".  This was a plumbing mistake and long past.  I am pretty sure I will just adapt from 3" to 4" so the roof flashing seals properly.

There is 3" pipe already ran to the attic from the basement.  Should I rerun 4 inch pipe all the way from the concrete 3" coupler, or just use the adapter in the attic before I go out the roof?